# Return the indices of the two numbers such that they add up to a specific target

Tags: functional-programming, kotlin

(...as I learn Kotlin) I want to get the indices of the two numbers such that they add up to a specific target from a given array of integers.

Solution:

```
fun sum(values: Array<Int>, result: Int): Array<Int> {
  for ((i, e1) in values.withIndex()) {
    for ((j, e2) in values.drop(i + 1).withIndex()) { // ...or: values.drop(i + 1).forEachIndexed { j, e2 ->
      //println("$i : $e1 >> $j : $e2")
      if (e1 + e2 == result) {
        return arrayOf(i, i + j + 1)
      }
    }
  }
  return emptyArray()
}
```

Test cases:

```
class SumTest {
  @Test
  fun testSum() {
    Assert.assertArrayEquals(sum(arrayOf(4, 7, 9, 10, 6, 34), 10), arrayOf(0, 4))
    Assert.assertArrayEquals(sum(arrayOf(5, 7, 9, 10, 21, 34), 43), arrayOf(2, 5))
    Assert.assertArrayEquals(sum(arrayOf(2, 7, 11, 15), 9), arrayOf(0, 1))
    Assert.assertArrayEquals(sum(arrayOf(2, 7, 8, 6, 20), 11), emptyArray())
  }
}
```

I know this is a pretty simple algorithm, but I would like to avoid the `return arrayOf(i, i + j + 1)` and modifying the `values` array in the second loop (`values.drop(i + 1).withIndex()`) if possible. A functional-towards approach would be great!

Comment: Is it possible that this is the first exercise at Leet code :?

Comment: I found it in a list of interview questions for Amazon; does it matter anyhow?

Comment: Not really I'm just asking. It's just for the tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Kotlin's `Array<Int>` is equivalent to Java's `Integer[]` (boxed array). You probably want Kotlin's equivalent of Java's `int[]` though (primitive array): `IntArray`.
2. `drop` and `withIndex` can be very handy but for simple loops like this they slow things down because they consume more memory than simple index loops. I did some quick benchmarks and in this scenario simple index loops (see below) were 10 times faster.
3. This function looks like a specialized `indexOf` function. You could write this as an [extension function](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html#extension-functions). e.g. `indexPairForSumOf`.
4. `e1` and `e2` are okay as names but `augend` and `addend` would be much more descriptive.
5. [Dair](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/82612/dair) also [points this out](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/151009/91387) but instead of returning an array it seems more appropriate to return a `Pair<Int, Int>?`.

Here is my take on the code if I were to create such a specialized function:

```
fun IntArray.indexPairForSumOf(sum: Int): Pair<Int, Int>? {
    for (augendIndex in indices) {
        val augend = this[augendIndex]
        for (addendIndex in augendIndex + 1..lastIndex) {
            val addend = this[addendIndex]
            if (augend + addend == sum) {
                return Pair(augendIndex, addendIndex)
            }
        }
    }
    return null
}
```

However, I recommend creating a more generic `indexPairOf` function (then you can find a pair of indices for the sum, difference, product, quotient, etc.):

```
inline fun IntArray.indexPairOf(predicate: (Int, Int) -> Boolean): Pair<Int, Int>? {
    for (firstIndex in indices) {
        val first = this[firstIndex]
        for (secondIndex in firstIndex + 1..lastIndex) {
            val second = this[secondIndex]
            if (predicate(first, second)) {
                return Pair(firstIndex, secondIndex)
            }
        }
    }
    return null
}

fun IntArray.indexPairForSumOf(sum: Int) = indexPairOf { augend, addend ->
    augend + addend == sum
}
```

Usage:

```
intArrayOf(4, 7, 9, 10, 6, 34).indexPairForSumOf(10)
```

Answer (score 4):

## `sum`

The word `sum` sounds like your taking an iterable of some sort and summing all the values in it. `sumsTo` would be a better name. Even then, I would expect to return all possible pairings, which the code doesn't currently do.

## `result`

I wouldn't call it result. I'm not that familiar with Kotlin, but sometimes APIs will write to the value you pass in and so the function doesn't return anything but it modifies the `result` variable. Maybe `target` is a better choice?

## `Pair` datatype

I would change your datatype from `Array` to `Pair`. You are returning a pair of integers satisfying the equation so why choose an array when there is a `Pair` data type object? I also suggest that if no solution is found that you, yes, return `null`.

`null` is often a bad design choice, but I strongly believe this is the exception. If there are no solutions we say that the solution set is null (or the empty set). So if there are no pairs the solution set is null. Reads just like math.

## Generalizing to `Iterable`

You could just iterate over an array of values, but more generally you probably want to iterate over an `Iterable` collection of integers.

The one cost of this is you have to say `arrayOf(...).asIterable()`.

## The code

```
fun sumsTo(values: Iterable<Int>, target: Int): Pair<Int, Int>? {
  for ((i, e1) in values.withIndex()) {
    for ((j, e2) in values.drop(i + 1).withIndex()) {
      if (e1 + e2 == target) {
        return Pair(i, i + j + 1)
      }
    }
  }
  return null
}
```